# Creating token accounts using InterfaceAccount

Tags: anchor, spl-token, token-2022

I'm using Anchor 0.28.0 and want to use [this new feature](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2460) that lets you specify which token program to use.

It looks very practical because it's used almost the same way as standard SPL accounts but I'm getting an error `Error: Signature verification failed` when trying to send my transaction.

Investigating further, it seems to be caused by the Token account that cannot be created. My CPI context is defined like so:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateMetadata<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        seeds = [
            AUTHORITIES_SEED.as_ref(),
            authorities_group.id.as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub authorities_group: Account<'info, AuthoritiesGroup>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::authority = authorities_group,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::token_program = token_program,
    )]
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = authorities_group,
        token::token_program = token_program,
    )]
    pub token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        space = Metadata::LEN,
        seeds = [
            METADATA_SEED.as_ref(),
            mint.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub metadata: Account<'info, Metadata>,

    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Everything works fine if I simply delete the `token_account`. I followed what was described in the PR to write that code but it seems like token account creation is not well supported yet.

I made sure that the associated token account was created using the correct token program as shown below:

```
getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mintKeypair.publicKey,
    holder.publicKey,
    true,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
)
```

Trying to create the token account before the instruction does not work because I need to mint to exist but it's created by the instruction.

Are there known solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking the question on Anchor's Github, I got the answer that worked for me: I forgot to add the associated_token_program `pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,`

You can find details here: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2460#issuecomment-1673627863

Answer (score 0):

Once defining the accounts within the instruction struct, is there anything special that needs to be done within the function to get the instruction to pass? I’m trying to create a token using the Token-2022 program as well.

Comment: Here is a minimal example of how to set up the interface token/mint accounts in Anchor: https://beta.solpg.io/https://github.com/solana-developers/anchor-examples/tree/main/account-types/InterfaceAccount

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look